# Types permitted in for loop variable declarations?

Tags: java, for-loop, variable-declaration

I've done some searches and couldn't find a list of valid types to use in for loop initialization statements.  Is there a fixed list of types that can be used in `for` loop variable declarations?  For instance, consider the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // ...
for (String str = "a"; str.length() < 10; str+="a") // ...
```

The first works, but I don't think the second will. Is there a list of all the types which are permitted in a for loop initialization?

Comment: Have you tried the second? You can use whatever type you want, there's no restrictions.. you can even initialize multiple variables, as long as they're all the same type.

Comment: Oh, wow, I was told by my lecturer that there were restrictions on types in for loops... didn't bother to test it myself. Sorry

Comment: Ah, well, your lecturer should have a look at the [the `for` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14) in the Java language specification, then. :)  There are restrictions on what can be there;  either multiple statements separated by commas, or a declaration of one or more variables, and the condition expression has to be boolean, but there's no restriction on the types of variables that can be declared.

Comment: A mod can delete this question if they want, or simply leave it

Comment: I don't think it's a terrible question.  You had a valid question, and and showed examples of what you knew would work and what you suspected wouldn't, and clarified in the comments _why_ you thought it wouldn't work.  Maybe there are languages out there that _do_ restrict the type of iteration variables you can use.  If someone's coming from one of those languages, this could help them.

Comment: IMHO your lecturer deserves a rap over the knuckles for that misinformation.

Comment: It's possible that your lecturer meant that there are restrictions on the types you can use in for loops for **homework** assignments. While you can technically toss almost anything you want into the initialization of a for loop, it's often bad practice to do so, and he/she might be trying to steer you in the right direction by restricting you to only a few common initialization idioms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the Java language specification for [the `for` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14). You can declare and initialize any type of variable in a `for` loop, and can even declare multiple variables, so long as they're all the same type.  The relevant productions in the grammar are:

```
BasicForStatement:
    for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) Statement

ForInit:
    StatementExpressionList
    LocalVariableDeclaration

LocalVariableDeclaration:
    VariableModifiersopt Type VariableDeclarators

VariableDeclarators:
    VariableDeclarator
    VariableDeclarators , VariableDeclarator
```

This means that you can do any of the following, e.g.,

```
for ( ; … ; … )                         // no variable declaration at all
for ( int i; … ; … )                    // variable declaration with no initial value
for ( int i=0; … ; … )                  // variable declaration with initial value
for ( int i=0, j=1; … ; … )             // multiple variables
for ( final Iterator<T> it = …; … ; … ) // final variable
```

The first example there shows that you don't need any variables at all, and as [pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341216/java-for-loop-initialisation-types#comment28653740_19341264), you don't have to have a `ForUpdate` either.  The only constraint is that you must have an expression in the middle, and it needs to be a boolean valued expression.

As an aside, the `ForInit` can also be a `StatementExpressionList`, which means that instead of declaring and initializing variables, you can also just execute some statements. E.g, you could do this (but this isn't a particularly *useful* example):

```
for ( System.out.println( "beginning loop" ; … ; … )
```

This could be useful, I suppose, in simulating a `do/while` loop (if you wanted to do that), if the body is a simple function call:

```
for ( method() ; condition ; method() );
```

Comment: While he's working on it; the short answer is that the middle (the `Expressionopt`) has to evaluate to a `boolean` or a `Boolean`, but there's no such restriction on the types for other two parts.

Comment: @DennisMeng That's a good point.  I don't think it's exactly what OP's asking, but it's a good point.  The other two parts don't even have to be present!

Comment: In particular, `for(;true;);` should be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Second one also will work fine. You can use any type for for loop

```
 for(String str="a";str.length()<10;str+="a")
    {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

I just tried for your scenario and result is

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
```