# Initializing a for loop with 2 variables

Tags: java, for-loop

I really don't understand why this wont work...

```
    for (int i = 1, int k = 2; i<=4000000; i++) {

    }
```

While this will...

```
    for (int i = 1; i<=4000000; i++) {

    }
```

I need to initialize two variables but when I try the first code  it wont compile, the code looks correct??

Comment: Basically I was using declaring each variable as an int individually which wont complile...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to initialize multiple variables, then they need to be of the same type, and you have to use just one declaration, so it would look like this:

```
for (int i = 1, k = 2; i<=4000000; i++ ) {

}
```

I wrote a bit about the syntax of `for` loops in response to [Types permitted in for loop variable declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19341216/1281433) This isn't quite the same question, but the answer makes sense here, too I think.

In general, you can have a look at the Java language specification for [the `for` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14). You can declare and initialize any type of variable in a `for` loop, and can even declare multiple variables, so long as they're all the same type.  The relevant productions in the grammar are:

```
BasicForStatement:
    for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) Statement

ForInit:
    StatementExpressionList
    LocalVariableDeclaration

LocalVariableDeclaration:
    VariableModifiersopt Type VariableDeclarators

VariableDeclarators:
    VariableDeclarator
    VariableDeclarators , VariableDeclarator
```

This means that you can do any of the following, e.g.,

```
for ( ; … ; … )                         // no variable declaration at all
for ( int i; … ; … )                    // variable declaration with no initial value
for ( int i=0; … ; … )                  // variable declaration with initial value
for ( int i=0, j=1; … ; … )             // multiple variables
for ( final Iterator<T> it = …; … ; … ) // final variable
```

The fourth case is the one that you're concerned with at the moment.

As an aside, the `ForInit` can also be a `StatementExpressionList`, which means that instead of declaring and initializing variables, you can also just execute some statements. E.g, you could do this (but this isn't a particularly *useful* example):

```
for ( System.out.println( "beginning loop" ; … ; … )
```

Answer (score 1):

Change as `for (int i = 1, k = 2; i<=4000000; i++) {`

From [Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

The general form of the for statement can be expressed as follows:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

- The *initialization* expression initializes the loop; it's executed
  once, as the loop begins.
- When the *termination* expression evaluates to false, the loop
  terminates.
- The *increment* expression is invoked after each iteration through the
  loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or
  decrement a value.

You can initialize as `int i=1,k=2;`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1, k = 2; i<=4000000; i++) {
```

Answer (score -1):

2 consecutive initializations should be semi-colon separated like

```
int a; int b;
```

In the above case you've have separated them using a comma and so it gives a compilation error.
Regards.

Comment: No. Your answer isn't correct for the initialiser of an `if` block - see the other answers. Somebody has flagged your answer as either 'not an answer', or 'very low quality', and [I am reviewing that flag in a review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18647242). You are attempting to answer the question, so even though I think your answer is wrong, I won't recommend it is deleted in my role as a reviewer, because a downvote is the right course of action here.